# Validating duplicates

Tags: php

I am new to this so please pardon me if I am repeating.  I not a PHP guru but as part of my learning experience I have hit an stumbling block.

I have a HTML form which has 5 dropdown select elements.  They all populated from the database, which has about 20 fruits name.  My itention is, user are not allowed to choose a duplicate fruit in ther section.  For example;
If user selects "Banana" in the first select box and then the user selects "bananas" in either one or more select boxes, it will simply print our warning message to say there is a duplicate value exist.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>" method="post">
<select name="plate1">
    <?php foreach ($fruits as $fruit) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $fruit['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $fruit['name']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
<select name="plate2">
    <?php foreach ($fruits as $fruit) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $fruit['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $fruit['name']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
<select name="plate3">
    <?php foreach ($fruits as $fruit) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $fruit['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $fruit['name']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
<select name="plate4">
    <?php foreach ($fruits as $fruit) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $fruit['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $fruit['name']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I am awarer that, there may be much simpler way of creating the form elements without having repeat myself but as I said I am here to learn and your suggestions are really welcomed.

Thanks in advnce for your help!

Comment: well, "you" have that code, remember that and there isn't much we can do here.

Comment: You typically want to implement such thing as logic on the client side, so in javascript, not php. Otherwise you'd only be able to generate such a warning after a full page reload.

Comment: @arkascha The form submits itself, so the message is shown after the post back is fine.  I am trying to avoid javascript, but if that is the last resort then I don't mind either.

Comment: Then you just need to let user submit the form, then in the $_POST['select_box_name_1'] !== $_POST['select_box_name_2'] .... if they are echo you just need to return an warrning, in your HTML you can have a error message handler

Comment: please add some code to your question!

Comment: You can try out some solutions listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151402/how-to-select-unique-values-from-multiple-dropdown-lists-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this to build your select boxes:

```
<?php
for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
    echo '<select name="plate['.$i.']">';
    foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
        echo '<option value="'.$fruit['id'].'">'.$fruit['name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

When you retrieve these values in PHP after the form is submitted, they will all be in an array `$_REQUEST['plate']`. You can check that they are all unique (ignoring select boxes that were not used) using the following:

```
<?php
if (count(array_unique(array_filter($_POST['plate']))) === count(array_filter($_POST['plate']))) {
    // success
}
else {
     $message = "Duplicate values detected.";
}
```

You could then do something with the `$message` to display it to the user.

Comment: Thanks @Josh H, I knew I was at right place to ask the question!